# Where is the scene in Undertale where Papyrus and Sans discuss finding a weapon?

Tags: undertale

I've seen images of a scene in Undertale where sans and papyrus discuss searching for some kind of weapon. It looks like it's in some kind of stone storage room with barrels on the bottom right. I'm not sure if it is legit or not. It was quite a while ago. I've seen playthroughs of the true pacifist and true genocide runs, so perhaps its a scene from the neutral playthroughs (other than the required "neutral" ending needed to trigger true pacifist). The scene is probably in reference to the whole time travel timeline issues sans mentions in the genocide run, but when I saw it I originally took it to mean that him and papyrus were villains (as I hadn't yet seen the game's story in full). Could someone explain where this is if it's actually in undertale? It seems like something not required yet considering it was right around 2015 into 2016 I doubt the fanfiction was that strong yet in terms of fangames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Undertale and have played through many times, from true pacifist to genocide to the 'corrupt pacifist' after genocide. I have never seen Sans and Papyrus talking about a weapon together in the way you describe. The most I saw them talk about anything considered dangerous (besides the protagonist) would be Papyrus's traps.

That being said, I have never modified my game files to let me have "Fun" value events. I've looked around a bit and haven't found anything but its hard to know for sure without looking myself.

If anyone can confirm that theres nothing of the sort even when playing with the undertale.ini file 'fun' capitalized to "Fun" that would be great.

Comment: Thanks. It looked kind of papyrus's garage and I think they were discussing gaster blasters. So I'm not sure if maybe it's a blended thing like "this only happens if you do xyz". Thanks.